# Virtual desktop, thin client, infrastructure

Tags: virtual-machine, vdi

I want to create VDI. I have a server that runs ESXi 5.5, a Windows Server 2008 R2 that I have install VShephere

As I said what I want to create a virtual machine then connect them to thin clients. Anyone knows what I need to to do that? Because I tried but i can't find how to connect the virtual desktops with the clients.

Comment: Can you add clarity to your question? Is that you'd like to access/RDP VMs in host or to create VDI? Those two are different processes btw..

Comment: i want to create a factional VDI system how im gonna do it use horizon use esxi or all toghethere that is what i cant understand